# SQL Check for port is available

Tags: sql

I've two tables.

First Table: Ports

```
Column: PORTID - integer
Column: FRONTINTERFACE - varchar  (eg, "RJ45", "BNC", "SC", "FC", "-")
Column: REARINTERFACE - varchar   (eg, "RJ45", "BNC", "SC", "FC", "-")
```

Second table: PortUsed

```
Column: PORTID - integer
Column: Facing - varchar(1) (eg, "F" or "R")
```

The ports table contains all the ports info including the front and rear interface type. If not available then the respective interface is set as "-"

If the port is used, the table PortUsed will store the PortID and the Facing.

Can anyone help with a sql query to check if the port is available.

Requirement 1: Check that the PortID and Facing is not inside the PortUsed Table to determine that the port is not in use.

Requirement 2: Check that the respective Front or Rear Interface is not "-"

I'm able to get the results in 2 seperate sql query but it is too slow. So looking for a sql query to combine the two. I also do not want to use stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Ports a left join PortUsed  b on a.portid = b.portid
where b.portid is null 
  and a.FRONTINTERFACE <> '-' 
  and a.REARINTERFACE <> '-'
```

i would suggest to change '-' in frontinterface and rearinterface into nulls

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working properly' what exactly is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Took me days to figure out how to get the correct results.

```
SELECT PortID FROM Ports
WHERE (PortID = @PortID) 
AND (FrontInterface <> '-') 
AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT PortID, Facing
                FROM PortUsed 
                WHERE (PortID = @PortID) AND (Facing = @Facing)
                )
    )
```

Replace the FrontInterface with RearInterface if checking for Rear facing.